# Is it correct to say "work with a particular amount of money" meaning to consider if it will be enough?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice

Would you tell me if it is correct and natural to say *work with a particular amount of money* meaning to consider if it will be enough? For example:

> I'm sure if I can knock the price down to 200. I need to check with my supervisor if I can **work with** that money.

If it's not natural, would you tell me what you would say?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if we omit the first sentence, it looks like that this "money" is stolen or has been acquired by illegal means. So, it is better to say "this amount of money" or maybe "this much".
Another thing, I am not a banker or in marketing business, but as far as I know it's not right to use "knock the price down" as phrase. They may have the term "knockdown price" but, it functions as a noun. So, instead of that use "bring down the price" which is perfectly normal.